# Certain webpages only half loading

Tags: google-chrome

Good day,

Since moving house and having my new internet (and new ISP) installed, some web-pages only half-load and I constantly get cloud-flare warnings requesting that I confirm that I am not a robot. I did not have this problem with the previous ISP. I have attached some examples of the issues I'm having. This does not appear to be a "Chrome-only" thing as I get the same results with IE.

- **1. The first image shows the web page loading, but not giving all the information.**

[image: Half-loading page]

- **2. The second image shows the warnings that constantly pop up.**

[image: Cloud-flare warning]

- **3. The third image is just an example of buttons that won't load on clicking, and some of those buttons don't even let me click them at
  all.**

[image: unclickable buttons]

**Issue:**
Can't load into certain pages, and can't click certain buttons, and keep getting this cloud-flare thing.

**Things I have tried:**
 - Restarting computer 
 - Reinstalling chrome 
 - DNS flushing using the command prompt 
 - Changing DNS to the google DNS

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagining your computer is the same, but your router is new/different (for the new ISP)?  Maybe your computer has existing proxy settings which were specific to your old ISP, and won't work for the new one.
Search 'proxy' in Windows search and disable any custom proxies.

Comment: Hello, I did as you suggested and the only thing that was enabled there is "automatically detect settings".

Comment: Try a second computer (friend/neighbour) on your home wifi or ethernet, to see how they go.  This could help identify if it's the router/connection/ISP, or just your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue as well when i moved into my new house. When i researched some more and talked with my tech-savvy cousin, he said that it could be because the internet connection isn't strong (some of the data gets lost in the way) or the ISP isn't allowing you to do the things that you want to do. Sometimes this occurs when you are asking for a lot of data. It is a security feature. Call them and ask why this is happening. Maybe it's different.

Also, check if you have a VPN on. I could also disrupt the websites.

Hope this was useful!!

Comment: Glad to see it hasn't only been me. I have spoken to the ISP and am waiting for their response. The odd thing is that my neighbour (with the same ISP) is not having this issue.

Comment: Hi again. i just posted another response. See that. It may help.

Comment: Oh, i forgot something. What is your ISP? If i know, then i could probably find the issue. Sometimes (in Australia, for example, you need to wait five days on this ISP to give you full clearance on internet usage {before that, the data is corrupted}), the provider [depending from which country it originated] may change certain allowances because of things that happen around the world (eg. political stuff).

Comment: I'm based in South Africa and the ISP is a local provider that I used before. (moved out a house with that ISP, then back into the same house with the same ISP and equipment from then). I'm not sure if they have any policies like that, but I'll check

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting a different device (like an Xbox, or PS, or your phone) and see what happens. If it can connect to the devices mentioned above correctly, then the problem is with your PC or laptop or apple device.

Comment: Seems my phone doesn't have any issues with the "takealot" site, but I think that's because the site has a mobile version. It still struggles with the PSN store, though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue had to do with the IP address. They gave me my own one and all was well in the world.